why does SQL Server log recovery replay to disk, instead of to RAM
SQL Server’s docs talk about applying committed transactions to data files during crash recovery, kind of like it was doing an immediate checkpoint. This is supposed to happen prior to undoing uncommitted transactions, which must happen to complete the recovery process.
Why does it flush committed transactions to data files immediately, instead of just loading dirty data into the RAM cache (the same way the data was stored in cache + logs, prior to the crash) and then let it be written out as part of the next checkpoint? It seems like this could needlessly lengthen crash recovery time.


Why does it flush committed transactions to data files immediately, instead of just loading dirty data into the RAM cache (the same way the data was stored in cache + logs, prior to the crash) and then let it be written out as part of the next checkpoint?

It does not write directly to the data files. The REDO process will load the pages needed in memory according to the outcome of the analysis pass and replay log records against those pages in memory, just as SQL Server does for all other modifications. Eventually, as part of the recovery process, a checkpoint will occur and this will write the dirty pages to disk.
You can check this yourself with procmon/etw if you're interested in understanding it further.

Thanks, that helps! But “Eventually, as part of the recovery process, a checkpoint will occur” — why can’t this be deferred until after recovery is complete?

@Dan Why would you wait that long? It also doesn't take into account that there could be a massive number of rollbacks (undo) which won't fit in memory, so it's going to be lazy written or flushed out anyway. I'm not sure why this, in of itself, is any major concern.
